# Строка в таблице базы данных wp_commentmeta ломает сайт после загрузки на хостинг

Tags: php, wordpress, хостинг

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при загрузке этой строки на хостинг, я не могу ничего редактировать в админ панель, что может быть не так с этим кодом? какая строка или строки могут ломать все?

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Время создания: Авг 30 2021 г., 09:37
-- Версия сервера: 5.7.33
-- Версия PHP: 7.2.34

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- База данных: `bpm`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `wp_commentmeta`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `wp_commentmeta`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_commentmeta` (`meta_id`, `comment_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
(1, 11, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'),
(2, 11, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1629806341');

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `wp_commentmeta`
--
ALTER TABLE `wp_commentmeta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  ADD KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  ADD KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191));

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `wp_commentmeta`
--
ALTER TABLE `wp_commentmeta`
MODIFY `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: наверное, у вас есть в консоли какая-то ошибка...

Comment: В какой именно консоли? Как проверить?

Comment: в консоли разработчика в браузере - чаще всего вызывается через f12, либо ctrl(cmd)+shift+c, далее вкладка Консоль (Console)

Comment: видимо я немного не так написал. Скорее ломает админ панель, но сайт работает. В админ панеле я ничего не могу изменять. А на сайте в консоле вот это и все  ` DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://jlipcaflaocihnmlhnhcfombgmmfglho/lib/backbone-min.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://jlipcaflaocihnmlhnhcfombgmmfglho/lib/chartist.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: Но это просто предупреждения и сайт работал с ними